# F# update or append an existing list

Tags: f#

I am trying to append to a list as below:

```
type Dabg = { trial : int list }

let talc = { trial = [1; 2] }

let Update(i) : Dabg =
    let newlist = List.append [(i)] talc.trial
    { trial = newlist }

Update 3
```

As I understand `Dabg` is immutable. So is typecasting `newlist` to `trial` inside the `Update` function actually just creating a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. You're not actually doing any casting here. Let's go through what your code *is* doing:

```
type Dabg = { trial : int list }
```

This declares a new type, specifically a [record type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233184.aspx), which contains a single name-value pair, named `trial` of type `int list`.

```
let talc = { trial = [1; 2] }
```

This creates an instance of the record type `Dagb`, setting the value of its `trial` to the list `[1; 2]`, and binding the instance to the name `talc`. Note that both `talc`, the instance, all of it's name-value pairs and all lists are immutable - you cannot make `talc` reference a different object, change which list `trial` references or alter the contents of that list.

```
let Update(i) : Dabg =
    let newlist = List.append [(i)] talc.trial
    { trial = newlist }
```

This defines a new function, named `Update` that takes a single parameter, the type of which is determined by type inference (to be `int`). It will return a value of type `Dabg`. When called, it will call `List.append`, which creates a **new list** containing the values of the first parameter (just `i`) followed by the values of the second parameter (the list `talc.trial`). The last line is implicitly the return value, the function returns a **new instance of type `Dabg`** where `trial` is set to the new list.

```
Update 3
```

This line calls Update with a parameter of 3. Tracing its execution reveals that it creates a `newlist` of value `[3; 1; 2]`, then returns a **new instance of type `Dabg`** with trial equal to the list `[3; 1; 2]`. **This return value is not used**, nor is `talc` altered, it still refers to `{ trial = [1; 2] }`.

Perhaps you intented to update the value of `trial`? In this case, you could capture the return value of `Update` and use it later. Like:

```
let newTalc = Update 3
doStuff newTalc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to write it. `f` is a predicate used to find the element to be changed. `sub` transforms the element, once found. The function returns an `option`, with `Some` containing the changed list and `None` meaning the predicate returned false for all elements.

```
let replace f sub xs = 
  let rec finish acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | x::xs -> finish (x::acc) xs
  let rec search acc = function
    | [] -> None
    | x::xs -> 
      if f x then Some(finish ((sub x)::xs) acc)
      else search (x::acc) xs
  search [] xs

//Usage
let xs = [1;2;3]
let result = xs |> replace ((=) 2) (fun i -> i * 2)
match result with
| Some ys -> printfn "changed list: %A" ys
| None -> printfn "not found"
//> changed list: [1; 4; 3]
```

Comment: Can we append to the existing list let xs = [1;2;3] and make it as let xs = [1;2;3;4;5]

Comment: No this is for some library which I am trying to make , but if I try the above then I get an error saying xs is not mutable

Comment: StackOverflow welcomes all programming questions that [demonstrate a basic level of understanding and effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Assuming that's the case, it should be relatively easy to modify my code to append if the element isn't found.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs . I was able to do it in this way type type Dabg =  { trial :  int list}
let talc = { trial = [1;2]}
let Update( i ) : Dabg =
           let newlist = List.append [(i)] talc.trial
           {trial=newlist}
Update 3

Comment: Consider the fact that you're getting a message about xs not being mutable as a sign you're doing it wrong.

Comment: After using the F# types and typecasting newlist to type trial as I mentioned in my previous comment  I am no longer getting the not mutable message.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you use the generic ResizeArray<_> type, which implements the List in System.Collections.Generic

You can use it like this:

```
let customers = new ResizeArray<Customer>()
customers.Add { Name = "some name here"; Id = 40 }
```

or like this:

```
let numbers = new ResizeArray<int>(seq { for number in [1..10] -> number * number})
```

using computation expressions as argument for the constructor.